# Parenting an object to a bone displaces it

Tags: armature

I'm trying to connect the arm (which is a separate object) to a bone.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lTOTfuP.png]

Here's what I'm doing:

- select the armature
- go into [pose mode]
- select the arm
- select the bone
- [make parent]
- [bone]

it ends up looking like this (zoomed out a lot):

[image]
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post your .blend, but try resetting the location, by pressing Alt+G

Comment: Tested in a simple case and it works Ok without any offsets. this might be better as a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand the way the hierarchy works and transforms etc... now I do. I had to "apply" the transformation of the objects.